# Swapping two characters in a string and store the generated strings in a list in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I want to swap every two characters in a string and store the output in a list (to check every string later wether it exists in the dictionary)

I have seen some codes that swap the characters all at once, but that is not what I'am looking for.

For example:

```
var = 'abcde'
```

Expected output:

```
['bacde','acbde','abdce','abced']
```

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a below list comprehension expression to achieve this:

```
>>> var = 'abcde'

#                         v To reverse the substring
>>> [var[:i]+var[i:i+2][::-1]+var[i+2:] for i in range(len(var)-1)]
['bacde', 'acbde', 'abdce', 'abced']
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the final entry from your expected output list is a typo, and that it should be `'abced'` to keep the pattern going, then here is one way (unsure yet if it generalizes correctly based on your use case):

```
In [5]: x
Out[5]: 'abcde'

In [6]: [x[:i] + x[i+1] + x[i] + x[i+2:] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
Out[6]: ['bacde', 'acbde', 'abdce', 'abced']
```

Answer (score 2):

A generator function will not use too much memory for longer strings:

```
def swap_pairs(s):
    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        yield s[:i] + s[i + 1] + s[i] + s[i + 2:]

>>> swap_pairs('abcde')
<generator object swap_pairs at 0x1034d0f68>
>>> list(swap_pairs('abcde'))
['bacde', 'acbde', 'abdce', 'abced']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `re` approach:

```
x = 'abcde'
[re.sub(f'(.)(.)(?=.{{{i}}}$)', "\\2\\1", x) for i in reversed(range(len(x)-1))]
# ['bacde', 'acbde', 'abdce', 'abced']
```

And a variant that skips double characters:

```
x = 'abbde'
[s for s, i in (re.subn(f'(.)(?!\\1)(.)(?=.{{{i}}}$)', "\\2\\1", x) for i in reversed(range(len(x)-1))) if i]
# ['babde', 'abdbe', 'abbed']
```

Comment: `reversed(range(len(x)-1))` ? I would have used something like `range(len(x)-1,-1,-1)` instead

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ... and promptly fallen for one of the traps. `range(len(x)-2, -1, -1)` should be the equivalent if I'm not mistaken. That's why I often find  `reversed´ more readable.

Comment: yes, I didn't test your solution. But I don't like using `reversed` on a `range` (code golfing habits ?)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm fine with either method. Do code golfers frown upon reversed ranges? They seem to be officially sanctioned considering that `range` objects have `__reversed__` method that returns a `range_iterator`, so that shouldn't be much slower if at all than manually reversing the range.

Comment: I don't think they care about speed. They care about code length.